# How do I go about using ReflectionFunction on filter_input()?

Tags: php, reflection

This is what I got so far;

```
<?php ReflectionFunction::export(new ReflectionFunction(filter_input()));
```

And I get this error:
Warning: filter_input() expects at least 2 parameters, 0 given in C:\wamp\www\POS\Ch4\inspect_filter_input_function.php on line 2

If I get rid of the parentheses, I get a warning but I the function's info. If I put two undefined variables it complains and I get nothing. I was wondering if I can get an example how to reflect functions with parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*ReflectionFunction::export()* expects a string (name of the function) as the first parameter, not a *ReflectionFunction* object:

```
ReflectionFunction::export('filter_input');
/* Output:
Function [ <internal:filter> function filter_input ] {
}
*/
```

or

```
$ouput = ReflectionFunction::export('filter_input', true);
```

An alternative is to directly print the ReflectionFunction object, since it implements the magic method __toString():

```
echo new ReflectionFunction('filter_input');
/* Output:
Function [ <internal:filter> function filter_input ] {
}
*/
```